# Qt Designer .ui and Visual Studio event handling

Tags: c++, qt5

I have made GUI of my window in QtDesigner called from Visual Studio.

It's ok. I have buttons in my interface, how to process event of pressing it from code of class inheriting QMainWindow?

I suspect it will be signals and slots mechanism, but how to do it.

How to link efectively preparing UI in QtDesigner and coding in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code generated from the Qt Designer form, there should be a class declared for each button.

So in your QMainWindow derived class, declare a slot like this:

```
    slots:
        void doSomething();
```

Define the slot just like you would a normal member function.

And connect it to the button like this, in your derived class's constructor or wherever else you're initializing it:

```
    connect(ui->nameOfButton, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
```

Where `ui` is a pointer to the generated UI class.